# Does uniform convergence of uniformly bounded, nonnegative, continuous functions to 0 on an infinite measure space imply integrals converge to 0?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \mu)$ be an **infinite** measure space. Let $f_n:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of **uniformly bounded, continuous, non-negative functions** on $X.$  Let $f_n \to 0$ **uniformly**.

Does this necessarily imply:

$$\int_{X}f_nd\mu \to 0?$$

If not, what other criteria do we need to ensure this? For the moment, some hints in the comments would be enough I think, as I'd like to work it out.

Comment: What if $f_n \equiv 1/n$?

Comment: @PhoemueX Oh wow, yes that works :)

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't imply.

Consider $X = \mathbb{R}$ and the sequence of functions such that 
$f_i(x) = 1/(i+1) $ for $-(i+1)<x<(i+1)$ and $0$ otherwise. You can easily make each $f_i$ continuous.

Everything is well-defined here: All $f_i$ are integrable and the result of integral is finite for all $i$; the function sequence converges and so does the integral sequence.

However, the function sequence converges to zero uniformly while the integrals don't.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the opening post, the convergence $\int_{X}f_nd\mu \to 0$ may not hold. PhoemueX gave the example $f_n \equiv 1/n$.

One has to add the assumption that for each positive $\varepsilon$, there exists a set $A=A(\varepsilon)$ of finite measure such that
$$
\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\int_{X\setminus A}  f_n  d\mu<\varepsilon.
$$
Then for a positive $\varepsilon$ and the corresponding $A$,
$$
\int f_nd\mu\leqslant \varepsilon +\int_Af_nd\mu\leqslant\varepsilon+\mu(A)\sup_{x\in X}f_n(x).
$$